# Arrange tabs in specific order for specific device size

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

https://codepen.io/TheNoviceProgrammer/pen/JJzvQq

For the desktop and iPad I want the div to display it as

```
|1||2| Which it is displaying.
```

but on sm(small) and xs(extra small) mobile device I want it to display it as
|2|
|1|

I have tried bootstrap's push and pull for xs and sm but it's not working. Whereas using push(col-md-push-xx) and (col-md-push-xx)pull for xs and sm the layout of iPad and Desktop changes to `|2|1|` while mobile display remains the same as
|1|
|2|

I think I may have used the classes in div in a wrong way, If someone can help me out it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

My HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-offset-right-0 col-xs-offset-right-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div>Labels & a bootstrap well</div>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-offset-right-2">
                    <div>Labels & a Table Gridview</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After using col-md-push and pull it overlaps as below for tablet and desktops:

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

While in mobile device its still showing same as the mobile screenshot above.

[Demo Pen](https://codepen.io/TheNoviceProgrammer/pen/JJzvQq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep your instincts are correct that push and pull are the way to go. They should be: col-md-push-6 and col-md-pull-6 for Bootstrap 3. Here's a [link to a pen](https://codepen.io/joseph-mueller/full/weOmaQ) that will help you. Also remember that the class sizing is inherent, you can call col-xs-12 and the small break point will inherit the 12 column width as well.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="well col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">Labels &amp; a bootstrap well</div>
        <div class="grid col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">Labels &amp; a Table Gridview</div>
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- container-fluid -->
```

Comment: I tried the way you mentioned above already, but its overlapping it in lg and md, while in sm and xs its still showing as |1||2|, I have edited my question with one more screenshot if you can help. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it man.

Comment: https://codepen.io/TheNoviceProgrammer/pen/JJzvQq Can you help me with this pen. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll take a look now

Comment: I tried your method given in your pen but its showing both the div at the right side overlapping each other. Also, the class well should not move to the right and grid to the left unless its a smaller device. I also tried removing addition css classes created by me, still its overlapping.

Comment: I just made updates see if that works. My suggestion would be control the overall width on medium break points and up with the outside div. Then just have the two children divs split the space on medium and up. https://codepen.io/joseph-mueller/full/MoxXOL

Comment: You have a div at the bottom with nothing in it <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-2"></div>. Did you want that to be below the table and well?

Comment: You have a div at the bottom with nothing in it <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-2"></div>. Did you want that to be below the table and well?

Comment: I just added that to leave some place at the right side of the screen. I tried your pen its working fine in the codepen.io but the same code is not working for me, idk what m i missing.

Comment: I used nested row just to show the content on the same line for larger device. I tried using single row but the well was apperaring at the top while the table was appearing at bottom of well for md,sm,xs devices.

Comment: The problem was with the bootstrap I was using, I downloaded the bootstrap from codepen.io and it seems to be working. Thanks for your time. Appreciate it man.